# How to delete the number from non repeating number array?

Tags: ios, objective-c, random, integer

I am trying this code for generating a random number and saving the list of numbers in an array, then i am trying to  delete those numbers from the list one by one which appeared once, e.g
1, 5, 9 , 4, 3, 7 ,6 ,10, 11, 8, 2 are the list of integers now 9 is appeared once and now i do not need 9 again.. this is my code of random non repeating numbers array.

```
NSMutableArray *storeArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];    
BOOL record = NO;
int x;

for (int i=0; [storeArray count] < 10; i++) //Loop for generate different random values
{
    x = arc4random() % 10;//generating random number
    if(i==0)//for first time 
    {
      [storeArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:x]];  
    }
    else
    {
        for (int j=0; j<= [storeArray count]-1; j++) 
        {
                if (x ==[[storeArray objectAtIndex:j] intValue]) 
                record = YES;
        }

        if (record == YES) 
        {
            record = NO;
        }
        else
        {
            [storeArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:x]];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
NSArray *arrRandoms = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:1,5,8,7,36,17,96,32,5,7,8,13,36,nil] ;     // This contains your random numbers

NSMutableArray *arrFresh = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

// Now removing the duplicate numbers

BOOL checkRepeat = NO;
int _Current;

for (int i=0; i<[arrRandoms count]; i++)
{
_Current = [arrRandoms objectAtIndex:i];

  if (i == 0)
     [arrFresh addObjects:_Current];
  else
  {
    checkRepeat = NO;

    for(int j=0; j< [arrFresh count]; j++)
    {
     if ( _Current == [arrFresh objectAtIndex:j])
       checkRepeat = YES;
    }

   if (checkRepeat == NO)
     [arrFresh addObjects:_Current];

  }
}
```

I think this code will work. Check It.

Answer (score 2):

try it

```
//**************remove repeat objects from array***************************//
    NSArray *noDuplicates = [[NSSet setWithArray: yourArray] allObjects];
```

Answer (score 2):

you add
.h file

```
BOOL isSame;
NSMutableArray *countArray;
NSInteger randomNumber;
```

.m file

countArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

```
//get randon no
-(NSInteger)getRandomNo:(NSInteger)range
{
    isSame=TRUE;
    while (isSame){
    isSame = FALSE;
    randomNumber = arc4random() % range;
    for (NSNumber *number in countArray){
        if([number intValue] ==randomNumber){
            isSame = TRUE;
            break;
        }
    }
    }
    [countArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:randomNumber]];
    return randomNumber;
}
```

Comment: its just getting number only, the numbers are repeating!

Comment: you add  
 .h file
    BOOL isSame;
    NSMutableArray *countArray;
    NSInteger randomNumber;
  
   .m file 
   countArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

Answer (score 0):

Tested Please try this,

```
NSMutableArray *storeArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableSet * setUnique = [[NSMutableSet alloc] init];
for (int i=0; [setUnique count] < 10; i++) //Loop for generate different random values
{
    [setUnique addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:arc4random() % 10]];

}
storeArray = [[setUnique allObjects] mutableCopy];
```

Comment: actually  ma scenario is different, i need one list of numbers, then i have to delete one b one all the numbers from it, through this em gettin new list all the time

Answer (score -1):

// check this how to get random number in array (i.e.. this array(below arr_numbers) contain non repeated number)

// for general purpose i am posting this.. so people cannot check for another answer

```
int num_count = 10;
    int RandomNumber;
    NSMutableArray *arr_numbers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (int j =0; j < num_count; j++)
    {
        RandomNumber = 0 + arc4random() % num_count;

        NSLog(@"%d",RandomNumber);

        if ([arr_numbers count]>0)
        {
            if (![arr_numbers containsObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:RandomNumber]])//
            {
                [arr_numbers addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:RandomNumber]];
            }

            if (j == num_count-1)
            {
                if ([arr_numbers count] != num_count)
                {
                    j = 0;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            [arr_numbers addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:RandomNumber]];
        }
    }
    NSLog(@"%@",arr_numbers);
```